# ext4 partition type unknow after restart and cannot be mount

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount, ext4, partition-recovery

After restarting my pc, I've stuck on error of my `/home` partition. It cannot be mount. Partition table is unknown. 
For this partition I had dedicated Goodram ssd 
250 gb drive. On this disk there was only one partition `/dev/sdb1` with `ext4` file system and was mounted in `/home`

Now I have errors:

```
`mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.`


kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ dmesg | tail 
[   49.547358] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[   49.547362] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
[   49.547363] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain uncore
[   49.547365] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram
[   64.136847] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[   64.603022] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[   64.603037] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[   64.603078] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[   66.907978] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link up
[   66.907984] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp2s0: link becomes ready
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$
```

`tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdc1
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.`

In GParted I have
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
I've taken 500GB HDD drive (`/dev/sdc`) and formated, shredded(3 times), and using clonezilla backup disk to disk from `/dev/sdb` to `/dev/sdc` So I have exactly (even uuid is the same) copy of my `/home` drive.

Now I would like to restore partition table on my ssd. If that is impossible I would like to restore as much files as possible.

Here is some console output:

```
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E1F5B6D8-76DD-40EF-BF83-CE8758E2CA29

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1050624 207005695 205955072 98.2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  435556352 468860927  33304576 15.9G Linux swap
/dev/sda4  207005696 435556351 228550656  109G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/sdb: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000957b3

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1          63 468857024 468856962 223.6G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/sdc: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000957b3

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1          63 468857024 468856962 223.6G 83 Linux
```

---

```
sudo blkid
/dev/sdb1: PARTUUID="000957b3-01"
/dev/sdc1: PARTUUID="000957b3-01"
```

And now I am on live cd os.
I need Your help, cause I did not had that problem ever (I am a 10 years linux user).

Please help me restore my partition table on /dev/sdb.

Comment: This is obviously not a partition table problem, but the filesystem on the partition is broken. If you are sure it was ext4, you can try to repair it with fsck.ext4.

Comment: I am not sure what is the problem, but I am sure that it was ext4 partition. Can You give me an example of this command? Can I try it at first on my backup partition?

Comment: Yeah sure you can use it on either sdb1 or sdc1 as you desire. Just run `fsck.ext4 -vn /dev/sdc1`, for example, and see what it gives you (and add it to your question). See its man page for [details](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/e2fsck.8.html).

Comment: I've followed Your first comment. Using this command `sudo fsck.ext4 -vy /dev/sda1` I've make it work again. Thanks. If You could post it as an aswer I would close the post.

Answer (score 1):

If you're positive it's an ext4 partition, you can try running fsck on it to see if the built in tools can recover the partition:

```
fsck.ext4 -vn /dev/sdc1
```

If that looks promising, run it for real:

```
fsck.ext4 -vy /dev/sdc1
```

If you're not positive, you can check your /etc/fstab for the entry for /home, or you can possibly try running something like

```
file -s /dev/sdc1
```

to see if it's recognized as an ext4 partition (your gparted output suggests it's not recognized however, but this can help in other cases in the future).